# How to enable connection to SSH tunnel from network (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a reverse SSH tunnel set up that is tunneling into my server. The remote servers web page can then be accessed via localhost:8080 on my server (just tested via curl). I want to make this service available to the rest of the network. How do I do that? UFW is inactive so I don't think that is what is causing me not to be able to connect from the network.

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding ports from remote machines to SSH tunnels is disabled by default on Ubuntu 18.04, it will only forward requests from `localhost`, as you have tested.

To enable remote machines from the network to access your SSH tunnel, you have to edit SSH Server settings:

```
echo 'GatewayPorts yes' | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

(you may notice there's a commented-out line `#GatewayPorts no` in this file, as it is the default)

Now restart the SSH service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Now port forwarding into your SSH tunnel should work when requested from remote hosts